# yum database is locked

Tags: database, rpm, yum

When I do `yum update` I get the following error response:

> One of the configured repositories failed (Unkown),
>        and yum doesn't have enough cached data to continue. At this point the 
>   only
>        safe thing yum can do is fail. There are a few ways to work "fix" this:
>
> 1. Contact the upstream for the repository and get them to fix the problem.
> 2. Reconfigure the baseurl/etc. for the repository, to point to a working
>          upstream. This is most often useful if you are using a newer
>          distribution release than is supported by the repository (and the
>          packages for the previous distribution release still work).
> 3. Run the command with the repository temporarily disabled
>              yum --disablerepo= ...
> 4. Disable the repository permanently, so yum won't use it by default. Yum
>          will then just ignore the repository until you permanently enable it
>          again or use --enablerepo for temporary usage:
>
>    yum-config-manager --disable 
>          or
>              subscription-manager repos --disable=
> 5. Configure the failing repository to be skipped, if it is unavailable.
>          Note that yum will try to contact the repo. when it runs most commands,
>          so will have to try and fail each time (and thus. yum will be be much
>          slower). If it is a very temporary problem though, this is often a nice
>          compromise:
>
>    yum-config-manager --save --setopt=.skip_if_unavailable=true
>
>    `database is locked`

I already did `yum clean all`, `rm -f /var/lib/rpm/__db*` and `rpm --rebuilddb` without any change.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

After spending couple of days, finally fixed this error by deleting the following folder

```
/var/lib/yum/history
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. After hours of searching, I found this and it worked perfectly. Thank you

Comment: I did spend couple of days :) Sharing is caring !!